# gitlab-ce how to see cas3 response attributes

Tags: gitlab, omniauth, cas

I am having trouble auto-filling the primary email for new users created when signing in with cas. The gitlab primary email should be obtained from the email attribute of my cas server using oath cas3. My cas is configured to send the email along with the uid/username but it only autofills the uid and not the email. Is there a way to debug this within gitlab to see what the cas' attributes are being returned from the cas auth?